# Can Kafka consumer on newer version consume message from Kafka producer on older version?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka producer that is using 0.80 Kafka version on one machine (eg. ip is 1.2.3.4), can I use kafka consumer that is using 0.10 Kafka version on another machine to consume the message?

I tried to write a consumer on the newer version which listen to 1.2.3.4:9092. But it says kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable. Is that not allowed? Or did I set something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: So you have a 0.8 Producer and Broker? And you're trying to run a 0.10 Consumer? Or you also have a 0.10 Broker? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Version 0.10.2 clients can talk to version 0.10.0 or newer brokers. However, if your brokers are older than 0.10.0, you must upgrade all the brokers in the Kafka cluster before upgrading your clients. Version 0.10.2 brokers support 0.8.x and newer clients.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_10_2_0

Comment: Thanks, Robin. I am using 0.8 producer and 0.8 broker on my vm and try to use a 0.10.0 consumer on my mac to get the message. So I should update my broker in your point?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference in Consumer API of 0.8 and 0.10. If you are in a position to upgrade your broker, then it's fine to use 0.10 consumer, however, you will also have to upgrade producers to the same API version.